# Indentify if page is loaded embedded or not

Tags: visualforce, page-layout

How to find out if page is loaded as embedded into page layout or directly by url? If it is not possible to find in serverside, is it possible to find out in Javascript? I need different Javascript logic depending if page was loaded embedded or directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded pages are rendered into an iframe, you can use `window.frameElement` to detect if the page is inside an iframe or not.

The documented standard for detecting this is this javascript:

```
var frameEl = window.frameElement;
// If we are inside a frame, then change its URL to 'http://mozilla.org/'
if (frameEl) {
  frameEl.src = 'http://mozilla.org/';
}
```

Related Documentation: [Mozilla - window.frameElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.frameElement)